# Red Hat AS 64-bit and multi core chip recognition

Tags: redhat, central-processing-unit, multi-core

We're running RH AS 64-bit 4.6 and for some reason after installing a Hitachi SAN driver, the kernal only recognizes 1 CPU of the 8 (4 dual core Opterons).  This server hosts an Oracle 9i database, so we're stuck with RH 4 (RH 5 isn't certified with 9i).  What do we need to do to get it to recognize all 8 cores?

Comment: additional info - when we try to boot in smp mode, kernel panic....

Answer (score 2):

Need more information:

- Did you install an SMP-capable kernel? Some distros offer the choice between a regular and a SMP kernel.
- Did the kernel recognize & boot the 8 cores without the SAN driver? If yes, the SAN driver may be buggy.
- Please post the panic message you get, that might give a clue.